# What is 3-symmetric drawing of graph

Tags: graph-theory, symmetry

i have searched through internet, but found only paid articles. Need to understand how Petersen graph can be contracted to K33, it says what through deleting the central vertex of 3-symmetric drawig. But what is 3-symmetric drawing?

Comment: They mean a drawing with 3-fold symmetry.  The most usual drawing has 5-fold symmetry, but you should be able to track down other drawings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a drawing of the Petersen graph with three-fold symmetry.  With the aid of the drawing, you should be able to find the needed contraction.
[image: Petersen graph with three-fold symmetry]

It is interesting that the method suggested in your hint, which requires the deletion of a vertex and its three incident edges followed by three contractions, is not the only way to find a $K_{3,3}$ minor in the Petersen graph.  An alternative requires no vertex deletions and only two edge deletions.  If the graph is drawn in the usual way with five-fold symmetry, then the two deleted edges should be parallel to each other.  Four contractions will then be needed.

Comment: Your picture are very well done, could you say me which graphics editor you used? Thanks.

Comment: @Yola : I made the graph in Mathematica.  I had to compute the vertex coordinates explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this should help. Here is a 3-coloring of the Petersen graph. Now contract so independent sets stay independent...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Petersen_graph_3-coloring.svg

In more detail, contract all blue to the neighboring green, and a pair of reds to get 3 reds and 3 greens...

Comment: The red vertex connected to three blue vertices should be the center vertex in the diagram with three-fold symmetry.  After contracting the blues to greens, don't you end up with $K_{4,3}$?  I think you will then have to delete a red rather than contracting it with another red.